# Sticky index reference while inserting into 2D list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, insert, permutation

While attempting to implement a function that produces all permutations given a list of integers, I'm seeing this behavior where the inserts are not occurring as expected.

My code:

```
def permute(nums):
    perms = [[]]
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        new_perms = perms * (i + 1)
        for j in range(len(new_perms)):
            new_perms[j].insert(j % len(perms), nums[i])
        perms = new_perms
    return perms
```

When calling `permute([1, 2, 3])` I'm expecting the perms to grow like:

```
[[]]
[[1]]
[[2, 1], [1, 2]
[[3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]
```

However, by the second iteration of the interior loop with `new_perms: [[1], [1]]` I'm expecting it to grow to `[[2, 1], [1, 2]]`, instead I'm getting `[[2,1],[2,1]]` and then `[[2,2,1],[2,2,1]]`. On each iteration of the j loop, the number is getting inserted into the current j position of *all* values of the list simultaneously on each iteration. Not what I was trying to do or expecting.

Ultimately, the code outputs:

[[3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1],[3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1],[3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1],[3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1],[3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1],[3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1]]

Either this is some subtle reference behavior (yay, learn something new!) or I'm just having a really dumb day ;) Any help appreciated.

PLEASE NOTE: I'm NOT asking for help with an alternate or optimal permutations function! I'm trying to figure out why this particular code is behaving in an unexpected way. Thank you.

Comment: You keep inserting *the same list object* multiple times

Comment: Also, the `*` operator **never copies** the elements inside a list. And `perms = new_perms` *doesn't create a copy*.

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, the copying was critical. That's why the inserts seemed to be 'magically' appearing in each of the nested lists. They are all the same object with multiple references / pointers in each element of the outer list. I'm sure there's a better way to solve it, but I ended up using copy.deepcopy(). Thanks for your hints/tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, learned a good one here. DEEPCOPY!

```
    import copy

    def permute(nums):
        perms = [[]]
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            len_perms = len(perms)
            old_perms = perms
            perms = []
            for _ in range(i+1):
                perms += copy.deepcopy(old_perms)
            for j in range(len(perms)):
                perms[j].insert(j // len_perms, nums[i])
        return perms
```